# QT menubar action receiver custom class

Tags: c++, qt

I have the menu bar that follows when you create a new project and i have set all of the senders to triggered() and I want the signals to be sent to a custom class I have. I have 3 static functions/slots in the class but none of them show up in the list.

```
#ifndef CONTENT_H
#define CONTENT_H

#include<QString>
#include<QObject>

class Content : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:

    QString filePath;

    Content();

public slots:
    static void Save(Content content, QString filePath);

    static Content Load(QString filePath);

    static Content New();
};

#endif // CONTENT_H
```

Comment: Show the menu bar code.

Comment: I don't have any menu bar code. Only have the mainwidow. The bar is part of that one. The only thing i have is the XML.

Comment: How do you connect the signals?

Comment: In designer with that green + sign.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Designer only allows to connect signals and slots between standard Qt widgets, and widgets that subclass them. You have to use [connect()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#connect) in the source. Here is a great example:

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/signalsandslots.html#a-small-example